# Adding PHP 5.6.12 to Ispconfig 3 (with Apache) on Debian 7

Tags: php, apache, debian, ispconfig

I have standard setup for Ispconfig 3:

https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-debian-wheezy-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3

Server is up to date. Everything working fine.

I'm trying to add PHP 5.6.12 following this guide:

https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-build-php-5.6-fpm-fastcgi-with-zend-opcache-and-apcu-for-ispconfig-3-on-debian-7-wheezy

Everything went ok until start fpm:

```
/etc/init.d/php-5.6.12-fpm start

Starting php-fpm [02-Sep-2015 18:16:07] ERROR: [/opt/php-5.6.12/etc/php-fpm.conf:540] value is NULL for a ZEND_INI_PARSER_ENTRY
[02-Sep-2015 18:16:07] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/opt/php-5.6.12/etc/php-fpm.conf'
[02-Sep-2015 18:16:07] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
failed
```

Problem is when this line is inserted at the end of /opt/php-5.6.12/etc/php-fpm.conf:

include /opt/php-5.6.12/etc/pool.d/*.conf

If I comment this line, fpm starts, but new PHP version in ISPconfig doesn't work.

I found this solution:

serverfault.com/questions/547394/is-there-a-limit-setting-a-php-admin-value-in-php-fpm

and used this fix:

github.com/DaveRandom/php-src/commit/9ad8e89d4f080626a92fc8817ab156c09b6b266a
and compiled again with it. Same result.

Any clue? Please help.

Comment: php-fpm.conf: [http://pastebin.com/Ums5JwRF](http://pastebin.com/Ums5JwRF)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today, you need an `=` just after `include`

Comment: Thank you for your response. We finally upgraded main PHP version from dotdeb repsoitory.